# Preventing CSRF?

Tags: csrf

I already seen some question from here (stackoverflow) and **[THIS](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/preventing-csrf-and-xsrf-attacks.html)** post, but I still have some questions...

1. Using hidden value in the post form and check it when post reach the server.

   - The hidden value can easy be copied and send exactly like the real one, "hard to guess" (like md5) will not help. (right?)
2. Setting a cookie when you reach the form and send the cookie value as a hidden value.

   - You can easily change a cookie value or send a custom cookie exactly like the real one using the same real hidden value. (right?)
3. Using 'timeout', the POST values cannot reach too late.

   - So, if you're slow you will fail when you try to set everything up with the hidden value. If you're fast it gonna work. (right?)

I want to be protected about CSRF...but how exactly I do it?

Comment: StackOverflow uses markdown - please use that when posting instead of HTML.

Comment: @Oded, thank you. I'll see how you edit it and learn about.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667189/simple-example-for-why-same-origin-policy-is-needed for a more general question about CSRF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way I found to prevent CSRF issues is:

1. On the server side, assign an [HttpOnly](https://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/) cookie to the client with a random (unguessable) token
2. Place a hidden field on the form with that cookie value
3. Upon form submit, ensure the hidden field value equals the cookie value (on the server side of things)

Comment: If I send a "custom" cookie (eg: using cURL) and a value exactly as the cookie value (custom cookie got "a" and hidden value got "a" too) it gonna work (I think), send the form values as the real one.

Comment: That will work, but CSRF isn't to prevent people from submitting forms all together, only to prevent people form posting forms as others (ie someone with a loggin in authorized state).  The whole purpose of the random token, is that user B (a hacker) does not know user A's token, and therefor cannot forge a request as them.

Answer (score -1):

If you make the following changes then I think you're safe

- no data updates should be allowed through GET (or better POST as well) (since both can be used through HTML forms)
- disable CORS on your server (or at least on endpoints that are critical and/or make changes to data)
- allow JSON-only APIs (ie. only accept input through JSON on critical endpoints at least)

Just to add to above: Do not use method overrides and do not support old browsers.

Comment: You just answered a question from 2012 and your answer is not even related to CSRF...

Comment: plz read the question "preventing CSRF?" and thats what I answered.