# PHP script executes IF statement even no POST has been done

Tags: php

I have two PHP script, and it seems the second script is not handling the `$_POST` correctly.

a.php

Important part:

```
echo "<form action='b.php' method='post'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='add' value='Add new items'>";
echo "</form>";
```

b.php

Important parts:

```
$error_variable1="";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")  {
    if (empty($_POST["something1"])) {
    $error_variable1="not correct";
    }
}

echo '<form action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'" method="post">';
echo '<textarea name="something1" rows="1" cols="10"></textarea>';
echo $error_variable1;

echo '<input type="submit" name="evaluate" value="Checking inputs">';
echo "  </form>";
```

Unfortunately even at the first start of b.php it displays / gives value to  $error_variable1 as "not correct."

But why is it working like this ? The user hasn't pressed the submit button yet. I want to give a "not correct" value for this variable when the "evaluate" submit button pressed.

Edit:

I am suspicious about that probably the POST (submit) from a.php is messing my b.php. What I would like is to display a text form with a submit button. When submit button has pressed ($POST) and the textarea is empty, then I want to show an error message to the user (not correct) and display the form again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409351/post-vs-serverrequest-method-post

Comment: Better use `isset(...)` instead of `empty(...)` and make sure you put NOT (`!`) in front of both.

Comment: if what you have for b.php is complete, it's missing a closing brace `}`. However, it's hard to figure out exactly what you want to do here.

Comment: `b.php` process values posted by `a.php`. So you have to modify your condition to differentiate `a` and `b` check. If you have nothing to check from requests coming from `a.php`, replace `a.php` form with a link (or replace `POST` method with `GET`)

Comment: Fred -ii-. sorry, will fix it.

Comment: Again, I don't know what you're trying to do here. I see an input with `Add new items` and this tells me you're probably using some JS to add items and trying to pass those to the 2nd page. I'm going to have to pass on this one. I'll just "watch" ;-)

Comment: Your `{` and `}` don't match up. Post an [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `empty($_POST["something1"])` to `empty($_POST["something1"]) && $_POST["evaluate"]`

Comment: I doubt this is the solution.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  I think he sends the post request to b.php, and $_POST["something1"] already empty its shows "not correct".

Comment: I for one have no idea what the OP wants to do here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Whats the meaning of OP ?

Comment: OP: *Original Poster/Person* ;-)

Comment: @mertizci It means the person who asks the question. It stands for **Original Poster**

Comment: Fred -ii-: I am suspicious about that probably the POST (submit) from a.php is messing my b.php. What I would like to display a text form with a submit button. When submit button has pressed ($POST) and the textarea is empty, then I want to show an error message to the user (not correct) and display the form again.

Comment: @TassMark that should be part of your question and for future visitors to the question today/or later.

Comment: @TassMark so change your `if (empty($_POST["something1"]))` with `if (empty($_POST["something1"]) && $_POST["evaluate"])`, i also edited my answer

Comment: Thank you Fred -ii- and mertizci.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strlen()` to check if variable is set.

This will count the number of digits entered and will return `false` when textarea is empty as the string length will be `0`.

```
if (!strlen(trim($_POST['something1']))) {
    $error_variable1="not correct";
}
```

---

Alternatively, check if the submit button is clicked:

```
if (isset($_POST['evaluate'])) {
    if (empty($_POST["something1"])) {
        $error_variable1="not correct";
    }
}
```

More information on `isset()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php.

Comment: No, it does not. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191626/isset-and-empty-what-to-use

Comment: `isset()` on a textearea won't do much good here. `isset()` is mostly effective with radio/checkbox.

Comment: you are right @ForceMagic I got a momentary muddle between `$var` and `$_POST['var']`.

Answer (score 2):

1) CSRF: people from other websites can choose to submit forms to your form handler, therefore you should add a **C**ross **S**ite **R**equest **F**orgery prevention value into a hidden field in your form, that updates every time the form is loaded, typically paired with a `$_SESSION` value. 
[Read more on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716674/preventing-csrf).

Using this unique "key" value you can then simply check at the top of your page if this `POST`ed key value is the correct value and that will confirm for you that the form has been posted.

so

**A.php**:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['obscure'] = some obscurevalue generated anew every page load.
echo "<form action='b.php' method='post'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='add' value='Add new items'>";
echo "<input tye='hidden' name='key' value='".$_SESSION['obscure']."'>
echo "</form>";
```

Then sends to **b.php**:

```
session_start();
if($_POST['key'] == $_SESSION['obscure'] && !empty($_POST['key'])){
   //This code will only run if the form has been correctly submitted.
}
```

The outcome of this is that you can be more sure that your code is run in the order it is intended and you can use the POSTED `key` value to confirm form submission.

---

As an aside as well it is bad practise to use `PHP_SELF` for form redirects. Use a static reference or use a properly uneditable value, as `PHP_SELF` can be abused by the end user.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following code segment in your code

```
if (empty($_POST["something1"])) {}
```

to the below one.

```
if (strlen($_POST['something1']) > 0) {}
```

Comment: "           " would return true

Answer (score 0):

You should definetly choose `isset()`! While `empty()` will return true even if its `null`, `isset()` will not!

`empty()` just checks if the given variable got a value. This can be anything! `Int`, `Float`, `String`, `Object` and also `NULL` - it does not matter. It will return `true`.

`isset()` instead will return `true` if the variable exists and is not `null`.

better choose `isset()` in this content ;)

EDIT:

see here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

and here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: From what I remember, using `isset()` for `<textarea>` will always return TRUE, *regardless*.